# How to customize @joelwenzel/ng-flowchart connectors using angular 12?

Tags: angular, flowchart

I need to build custom journey builder for one of my projects i want true or flase as connector how can i achieve this ?

I have tried several other plugins like gojs but with this i cannot customize the ui. That has been done using  @joelwenzel/ng-flowchart now i just want to add ability to add such type of connector  that works like true or false branch